# Is it allowed to call ICommunicationObject.Close() when the CommunicationState of channel is being in CommunicationState.Opening?

Tags: wcf, channel, channelfactory

Inside of `IDisposable.Dispose()` method I launch `ICommunicationObject.Close()` method of my channel. Is it allowed to call `ICommunicationObject.Close()` when the `CommunicationState` of the channel is `CommunicationState.Opening`?

I.e. is such checking sufficient for the `ICommunicationObject` instance closing?

```
ICommunicationObject commObj = channel as ICommunicationObject;
if (null != commObj &&
    commObj.State == CommunicationState.Opened ||
    commObj.State == CommunicationState.Opening) {

    commObj.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can simply check `commObj.State != CommunicationState.Closed`.

I've been running a variant of [A smarter WCF service client](http://www.michaeltaylorp3.net/a-smarter-wcf-service-client-part-2/) without issue for years.